# email successfully sent but not receive in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, phpmailer

**I am using the following code in xamp**

**email successfully sent but not receive.**

```
    $config=array(
                'protocol'=>'smtp',
                'smtp_host'=>'ssl://smtp.googleemail.com',
                'smtp_port'=>465,
                'smtp_user'=>'malikumair112233@gmail.com',
                'smtp_pass'=>'Mypassword1234$'

                );
            $this->load->library('email',$config);
            $this->email->set_newline('\r\n');
            $this->email->from('malikumair112233@gmail.com','VBUZZ');
            $this->email->to('webtrix001@gmal.com');
            $this->email->subject('helo test');
            $this->email->message('test test ');

            if($this->email->send()) {
                echo 'Message sent.';

            } else {
                show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
                echo 'Message has not been sent';
            }
```

It show me that Message sent but when I check my mail no email received.

Comment: Please don't include code as images. It is text, so include it as such. Nobody will copy your code from an image and try it out or might not even open the image.

Comment: Sir now check that please.

Comment: check your spam messages ..

Comment: not receive any spam message.

Comment: “webtrix001@gmal.com” → typo? did you mean gmail.com?

Comment: yes webtrix001@gmail.com

Comment: And please do not include real username and password here in.